# Responsive design: absolute positioned div in a table

Tags: css

[image]

This screenshot basically demonstrates what I'd like to do. Basically, when a user clicks the update icon, it opens a menu, with the now highlighted edit icon in the same position as the original icon.

However, when I change the screen size, the width of table rows change and the icons no longer line up.

[image]

I would like the icons to line up no matter what device is used, but am not sure how to achieve this.

The html + css of the unselected cell is this:

```
<td style="text-align:right; font-color=blue;">
    <span style="top:3px; position=relative;">
        icon code
    </span>
</td>
```

And of the selected cell:

```
<td>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:5px; right:3.5vw; width:370%;">
        ....
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but the simplest may be to just leave the icon alone, adding your menu and then using z-index to put the icon on top of it: (ignore any extra markup, I wasn't sure what your working example looked like)

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.mytable{
  width:100%;
  background:#FFF;
  font:500 24px/45px Arial;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom:none;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.mytable td{
  padding:0 25px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
}
.mytable td.menu{
  text-align:right;
  position:relative;
  overflow:visible;
  max-width:50px;
}
.mytable input{
  display:none;
}
.mytable i{
  position:relative;
  color:red;
  z-index:1;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.mytable input:checked + label i{
  color:blue;
  z-index:3;
}
.mytable input:checked ~ div{
  display:block;
}
.mytable div{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  right:8%;
  padding-top:35px;
  background:#FFF;
  box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:2;
}
.mytable ul{
  list-style-type:none;  
}
.mytable ul li{
  margin:0;
  padding:0 12px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>here.</td>
      <td class="menu">
        <input id="input1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="input1"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i></label>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>Menu item</li>
            <li>Other menu item</li>
            <li>This menu item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>here.</td>
      <td class="menu">
        <input id="input2" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="input2"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i></label>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>Menu item</li>
            <li>Other menu item</li>
            <li>This menu item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>here.</td>
      <td class="menu">
        <input id="input3" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="input3"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i></label>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>Menu item</li>
            <li>Other menu item</li>
            <li>This menu item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jm8wa6oz/

Comment: That's an awesome suggestion, and looks great in 90% of cases. Now I have the problem, in larger screen sizes, the icon is way out of alignment with the menu items (because the icon isn't moving, but the menu position changes based on the screen size).

Comment: Found a solution to that, instead of positioning with 'right', position with 'left' and a negative value. Go figure.